# How can I switch directly to a workspace using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-manager, workspaces, workspace-switcher

How can I set up a keybinding to jump directly to a workspace?

i.e. if I'm on workspace 4, and I know my editor is (always by personal convention) on workspace 2, I want to just hit Super-2 to jump straight there instead of having to think "Ok, that's two workspaces to the left, I need to do Super-Left twice".

More generally, I am trying to get compiz to behave more like a tiling window manager using minimally invasive things like custom keybindings; this is just where I'm starting...

Answer (score 1):

Ooops, not sure how I missed it; for some reason I didn't scroll and see more options:

System Settings -> Keyboard -> Navigation -> (Scroll down) -> Switch to Workspace 2

Answer (score 1):

you can set shortcuts for this by launching "keyboard" from the Dash and choosing the

shortcuts tab. Choose the "Navigation" option, then just change the various settings for

"Switch to workspace"

[image]

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/607637/minimize-maximize-current-window-keyboard-shortcut)